# Unable to find packages error

Tags: linux

I ran two commands:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Now if I try to install any software it is showing

> unable to find the package.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring because, you have removed the local cache of `apt` package manager. Run `sudo apt-get update` to get all packages list.

Comment: I did that one also but didnt working.still same issue

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get clean`.